# In Mono.Cecil, where does the Resolve() method get the definition from?

Tags: c#, .net, il, mono.cecil

I'm using `Mono.Cecil` to modify an assembly. Let's say I've modified the definition of `Method()` in-memory, and later I have a reference to it, possibly in the same `ModuleDefinition` being modified (but not necessarily)

Will calling `Resolve()` on that reference return the modified definition, or original definition? Where does Cecil get the definition from, exactly? How can I make sure I get the one I'm looking for?